# Facing Critical Performance issue in Primefaces 4 & 5

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I am working on a project which deal with heavy data sets. I am using **Primefaces 4 & 5**, spring and hibernate. I have to to display a very huge datasets such as min 3000 rows with 100 columns with various features such as sorting, filtering, row-expansion etc. My problem is, my applications took 8 to 10 mins to show the whole page as well as  other functionalities(sorting, filtering ) also takes a lot time. My client is not happy at all. However I can use pagination for this but again My client do not want paging. So I decided to use livescroll but unfortunately I failed to implement **livescroll with lazyload or without lazyload** as there were bugs in PF regarding livescroll. also i have posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195131/wrong-values-in-prowexpansion-and-empty-values-in-pcelleditor-on-scolled-p) earlier but no solution found.

This **performance** issue is very critical and show stopper for me. To show 3000 rows with 100 columns, the size of the page which is getting loaded is ~10MB.
I have calculated the time consumed by various **life-cycles of of JSF**, using **Phase-listener** I figure out that its Browser who is taking time to parse the response rendered by jsf. To complete the all phases my application took only 25 sec.
At minimal I want to increase the performance of my project. Please share any idea, suggestion and anything which could help to overcome this problem

**Note**: There is no database manipulations in getters and setters as well as no complex business logic.

**UPDATE  :**
This is my datatable without lazyload:

```
<p:dataTable 
                style="width:100%"
                id="cdTable"
                selection="#{controller.selectedArray}"
                resizableColumns="true" 
                draggableColumns="true" 
                var="cd"
                value="#{controller.cdDataModel}"
                editable="true" 
                editMode="cell"
                selectionMode="multiple"
                rowSelectMode="add"
                scrollable="true"
                scrollHeight="650"
                rowKey="#{cd.id}"
                rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                styleClass="screenScrollStyle"
                liveScroll="true"
                scrollRows="50"
                filterEvent="enter"
                widgetVar="dt4"
                >
```

Here everything is working except filtering. Once I filter then first page is displayed but unable to sort or livescroll on datatable. Note this I have tested in **Primefaces5**.

**2nd Approch**

**With lazyload with same datatable**
1) When I add **rows="100"** livescroll happens but problem with row-editing, row-expansion but filter & sorting works.
2) When I remove **rows** livescroll works with row-editing, row-expansion etc but filter & sorting dont work.

**My LazyLoadModel is as follows**

```
public class MyDataModel extends LazyDataModel<YData> 
         {

    @Override
    public List<YData> load(int first, int pageSize,
            List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        System.out.println("multisort wala load");
        return super.load(first, pageSize, multiSortMeta, filters);
    }



    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<YData> datasource;

    public YieldRecBondDataModel() {
    }

    public YieldRecBondDataModel(List<YData> datasource) {
         this.datasource = datasource;
    }




    @Override
    public YData getRowData(String rowKey) {
        // In a real app, a more efficient way like a query by rowKey should be
        // implemented to deal with huge data

    //  List<YData> yList = (List<YData>) getWrappedData();

        for (YData y : datasource) 
        {
            System.out.println("datasource :"+datasource.size());
            if(y.getId()!=null)
            {
            if (y.getId()==(new Long(rowKey)))
            {
                return y;
            }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(YData y) {
        return y.getId();
    }






      @Override
        public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
            /*
             * The following is in ancestor (LazyDataModel):
             * this.rowIndex = rowIndex == -1 ? rowIndex : (rowIndex % pageSize);
             */
            if (rowIndex == -1 || getPageSize() == 0) {
                super.setRowIndex(-1);
            }
            else
                super.setRowIndex(rowIndex % getPageSize());
        }



      @Override
        public List<YData> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {
            List<YData> data = new ArrayList<YData>();
            System.out.println("sort order : "+sortOrder);
            //filter
            for(YData yInfo : datasource) {
                boolean match = true;

                for(Iterator<String> it = filters.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    try {
                        String filterProperty = it.next();
                        String filterValue = String.valueOf(filters.get(filterProperty));
                        Field yField = yInfo.getClass().getDeclaredField(filterProperty);
                        yField.setAccessible(true);
                        String fieldValue = String.valueOf(yField.get(yInfo));
                        if(filterValue == null || fieldValue.startsWith(filterValue)) {
                            match = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            match = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        match = false;
                    }
                }

                if(match) {
                    data.add(yInfo);
                }
            }

            //sort
            if(sortField != null) {
                Collections.sort(data, new LazySorter(sortField, sortOrder));
            }

            int dataSize = data.size();
            this.setRowCount(dataSize);

            //paginate
            if(dataSize > pageSize) {
                try {

                    List<YData> subList = data.subList(first, first + pageSize);
                    return subList;
                }
                catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    return data.subList(first, first + (dataSize % pageSize));
                }
            }
            else
                return data;
        }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getRowCount();
    }

    }
```

I am fade up with these issues and becomes show stopper for me. Even i tried Primefaces 5

Comment: I can't see where 100 Columns would fit in the page, but anyhow pagination is the effective way to go with (there's a limitation after all) imagine google search results would appear all in the page with 3000 results! Pagination and Lazy Loading is the solution, and of course database indexing is also recommended. Live scrolling issue must be fixed in the latest 5 version.

Comment: @HatemAlimam thanks for your reply, Please check the updates.The problem is my client dont want pagination. Thats why I have to stick with livescroll, but livescroll itself contains bugs.

Comment: Lazy loading has other problems. You are not able to search in the page on client. If you use server side filter it's not easy to scroll to the right position. p:dataTable can be replaced by h:dataTable that performs better. Big tables has problems with performance on client side in browser. Showing big table in web technologies is not very good idea! It is job for desktop application. Much better is filtering and paging.

Comment: @lada.dvorak... thanks for your suggestion. But Paging is not acceptable from my client. So Only one option is left i.e. livescroll. I have almost nailed it, but filtering is not properly working. I will give it a try to use h:datatable, any other approch other than h:datatable.

Comment: Maybe you may talk your client into not using a web interface into this... It seems more suited for a desktop application, if you want to stick with the web maybe an Applet. Hey, if he only wants to surf the data opening an spreadsheet might be ok.

Comment: actually clients need some behaviors like spreadsheet over web.So what you guys are saying is with that huge amount of data, everyone will face the same problem. Is there anything which can handle such huge data with excel sheet like functionality(sorting,filtering,editing) on web.

Comment: Hmm one stupid idea ( avoiding real problem ), you can export all data to excel so user can edit it there. After he finished, he can import data via you application. ( im following this question because problem is very interesting. When i come home i will think about it again how i would solve it. I will edit this comment )

Comment: Modern versions of excel suport connecting to WebServices for obtaining data. I have not tried it though, so I do not know easily they do interact with java servers or how efficient they are for bulk loading. You could also try GoogleDocs, too.

Comment: @jNick... earlier this application was in excel, but now its need a lot of computation and other complex business on different scenarios and as a result we cant use excel sheet.SO my idea was lets forget about excel sheet but give it a try some real solutions which is more concerns with primefaces & jsf or other api. I am thinking about richfaces, guys what do you think about this?

Comment: @SJuan76... earlier this was in our mind, but because of client's requirements and other things we drop this idea, there is a client side api "slick grid" ,its shows large no. of data very effectively but again comes with no. of bugs, their features will fight with each other once we tried to combine those features.

Comment: http://madebyknight.com/optimizing-datatables-performance/ some useful tips

Comment: I think that the lazy load code has to be really improved. The data is loaded from database? You have to use the db function to sort and page, not to use sublist and Collection.sort. The best functional solution is to do as say jNick, with export to open with some kind of office. But if you want to load in the page you need to boost that lazy load

Answer (score 0):

If your data is loaded from db i suggest you to do a better LazyDataModel like:

```
 public class ElementiLazyDataModel extends LazyDataModel<T> implements Serializable {

        private Service<T> abstractFacade;


        public ElementiLazyDataModel(Service<T> abstractFacade) {
            this.abstractFacade = abstractFacade;

        }

        public Service<T> getAbstractFacade() {
            return abstractFacade;
        }

        public void setAbstractFacade(Service<T> abstractFacade) {
            this.abstractFacade = abstractFacade;
        }

        @Override
        public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
            PaginatedResult<T> pr = abstractFacade.findRange(new int[]{first, first + pageSize}, sortField, sortOrder, filters);

            setRowCount(new Long(pr.getTotalItems()).intValue());

            return pr.getItems();
        }

    }
```

The service is some kind of backend communication (like an EJB) injected in the ManagedBean that use this model.

The service for pagination may be like this:

```
@Override
    public PaginatedResult<T> findRange(int[] range, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {

        final Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("select x from " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " x")
                .setFirstResult(range[0]).setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);

        // Add filter sort etc.

        final Query queryCount = getEntityManager().createQuery("select count(x) from " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " x");
        // Add filter sort etc.

        Long rowCount = (Long) queryCount.getSingleResult();

        List<T> resultList = query.getResultList();

        return new PaginatedResult<T>(resultList, rowCount);
    }
```

Note that you have to do the paginated query (with jpa like this the orm do the query for you, but if you don't use orm have to do paginated query, **for oracle look at TOP-N query, for example: http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/top-n-queries.php**)

Remember your return obj must be contains also the total record as a fast count:

```
public class PaginatedResult<T> implements Serializable {

    private List<T> items;
    private long totalItems;

    public PaginatedResult() {
    }

    public PaginatedResult(List<T> items, long totalItems) {
        this.items = items;
        this.totalItems = totalItems;
    }

    public List<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public long getTotalItems() {
        return totalItems;
    }

    public void setTotalItems(long totalItems) {
        this.totalItems = totalItems;
    }
}
```

All this is useful if your database table is correctly setup, pay aptention to the execution plan of the possible query and add the right index.

Hope to give some hint to improve you performance

In the end, remember to your final user that the human eyes can't see more that 10-20 record at once, so it is very useless to have thousand record in a page.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the default *load* implementation which is used in the showcases of Primefaces. This is not the correct implementation for your case where you load your data from a database.

The load method should use the correct query with consideration of :

1) the filter fields that are used, example:

```
String query = "select e from Entity e where lower(e.f1) like lower('" + filters.get(key) + "'%) and..., etc. for the other fields
```

2) the sorting columns that are used, example:

```
query.append("order by ").append(sortField).append(" ").append(SortOrder.ASCENDING.name() ? "" : sortOrder.substring(0, 4)),..., etc. for the other columns.
```

3) The total count of your query WITH 1) attached to it. Example:

```
Long totalCount = (Long) entityManager.createQuery("select count(*) from Entity e where lower(e.f1) like lower('filterKey1%') and lower(e.f2) like lower('filterKey2%') ...").getSingleResult();
```