# Expand primefaces rowExpansion on rowSelect

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dataTable with a rowExpasion inside, i want to expand this based on rowSelection.

When the user clicks the row it expands that row, without the need of a `<p:rowToggler/>`

```
    <p:dataTable var="foo" value="#{fooBean.foos}" lazy="true" selection="#{fooBean.foo}" selectionMode="single" rowExpandMode="single"
        paginator="false" rows="10">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="PF('rowExpansion').expand(?)" />

        <p:column headerText="Value">
            <h:outputText value="#{foo.value}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:rowExpansion>
            sweetstuffinside
        </p:rowExpansion>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Also,i don't wan't to have the `<p:rowToggler>` visible, if possible.

Comment: It is all just html, css and javascript. There is a select event. In which you can call some javascript which in turn can do a 'click' on the rowToggler

Comment: @Kukeltje i don't know what exactly to call on this case, tried <p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="jQuery('').click()" /> but i don't know what to click so it gets only the row i want...

Comment: Break down your problem. First you need to get the right row. A little searching in google results in finding this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946557/to-get-the-row-number-of-the-selected-primefaces-datatable-row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies here: [PrimeFaces expand row on row click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787934/primefaces-expand-row-on-row-click)
Although that gave me different problems, it's another topic, this answer fulfill the need to expand the rows on click.

Remember you need to keep the `<p:rowToggler/>` inside the table as a column.

Just replace the `rowExpansion(PF('dataTableWidgetVar'));` for your correct datatable widgetVar

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
               rowExpansion(PF('dataTableWidgetVar'));
            });

        function rowExpansion(dataTable) {
               //dataTable should be the widgetVar object
               var $this = dataTable;
               //add the 'hand' when hovering on row
               $this.tbody.children('tr').css('cursor', 'pointer')
               $this.tbody.off('click.datatable-expansion', '> tr')
                  .on('click.datatable-expansion', '> tr', null, function() {
                     //before expanding collapse all rows
                     $this.collapseAllRows();
                     //toggle the current row the old toggler
                     $this.toggleExpansion($(this).find('div.ui-row-toggler'));
                   });
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Hello i got this Widget for var 'dataTableWV' not available! <p:dataTable tableStyleClass="dispo" var="element" id="tablaItinerario" value="#{disponibilidadBean.listadoItinerario}" selectionMode="single" rowExpandMode="single" rowIndexVar="cont" widgetVar="dataTableWV" selection="#{disponibilidadBean.registroItinerario}" rowKey="#{element.codigo}" > –

Comment: $this.collapseAllRows(); doesn't work. It's not a function. I'm using primefaces 4.0. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with the help of this custom method.

give 'togglerClass' this class like

```
<pou:column styleClass="togglerClass" style="width:16px">
    <pou:rowToggler/>
</pou:column>
```

JavaScript code here;

```
function prodsToggler() {
    $('.togglerClass div').click(function () {
        var currentTr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var $trs = $('.togglerClass').closest("tr").not(currentTr);
        $trs.each(function (index, el) {
            var $this = $(el),
                    $next = $this.next(".ui-expanded-row-content");

            $this.removeClass("ui-expanded-row");
            $next.remove();

            $this.find(".ui-row-toggler").removeClass("ui-icon-circle-triangle-s");
        });
    });
}
```

call this method in windows ready.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that works for PF 6.0.17 and includes adding the ENTER key to open and close the row.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    rowExpansion('tableEntity');
});

rowExpansion : function(dataTableWidgetVar) {
    // dataTable should be the widgetVar object
    var $this = PF(dataTableWidgetVar);

    // turn off row toggler events
    var togglerSelector = '> tr > td > div.ui-row-toggler';
    $this.tbody.off('click.datatable-expansion', togglerSelector);
    $this.tbody.off('keydown.datatable-expansion', togglerSelector);

    // add the 'hand' when hovering on row
    $this.tbody.children('tr').css('cursor', 'pointer');

    // now set the toggle to be the whole row
    togglerSelector = '> tr';

    $this.tbody
        .off('click.datatable-expansion', togglerSelector)
        .on('click.datatable-expansion',
            togglerSelector,
            null,
            function() {
                // toggle the current row
                $this.toggleExpansion($(this).find('div.ui-row-toggler'));
            })
        .on('keydown.datatable-expansion',
            togglerSelector,
            null,
            function(e) {
                var key = e.which, keyCode = $.ui.keyCode;

                if ((key === keyCode.ENTER || key === keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER)) {
                    $this.toggleExpansion($(this).find('div.ui-row-toggler'));
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
}
```